# Dynamic login_redirect_url in Django allauth

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm using `django-alluth` for social login. My concern is how do I login to a specific url instead of the fixed `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` in the `settings.py` file?

When I try removing the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` and setting my login page url as `accounts/login/?next=/some-url/` it doesn't work. It redirects to `accounts/profile` which is a 404 in my code.

Answer (score 5):

You need to override `get_login_redirect_url` in `DefaultAccountAdapter`.

```
# project/settings.py:
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'project.users.adapter.MyAccountAdapter'

# project/users/adapter.py:
from django.conf import settings
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter

class MyAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

    def get_login_redirect_url(self, request):
        path = "/accounts/{username}/"
        return path.format(username=request.user.username)
```

[docs](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#custom-redirects)

Answer (score 2):

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/afterlogin'
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATED_LOGIN_REDIRECTS = True
```

This works for me...

Answer (score -1):

Your answer seems to be here:

http://www.sarahhagstrom.com/2013/09/the-missing-django-allauth-tutorial/